# Are questions about finding team members for a game development project on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic

I am of course not asking about those "Would you like to join my team" job-postings disguised as questions which appear from time to time, but rather about generalized questions about where and how to hire developers, artists or other team members for a game development project.

The help center lists as [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions, among others:

- project management (testing, **team management**, scheduling, publishing, etc)

Assembling a project team is the first part of team management.

One recent question which was closed as off-topic through a moderator was *["Where can I find animators to create 3D models and animations for characters in 2d isometric game?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70179/where-can-i-find-animators-to-create-3d-models-and-animations-for-characters-in)* but I don't want to discuss this particular question but rather the issue in general.

Assuming that a question asks about recruitment strategy for a game development project and that it does address aspects specific to game development which don't apply to general software development (which would make it more fitting for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)) or even hiring personel in general (which would fit on [workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)), could the question be on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

> Assuming that a question asks about recruitment strategy for a game
>   development project and that it does address aspects specific to game
>   development which don't apply to general software development (which
>   would make it more fitting for programmers) or even hiring personel in
>   general (which would fit on workplace), could the question be
>   on-topic?

Possibly, if other factors did not contribute to it being off-topic (such as being a list-of-X question, or overly based on opinion, et cetera).

However, I'm finding it very difficult to think of good example where what you are suggesting would be there, but what I am suggesting would be absent. Do *you* have an example question that you are thinking of?

I don't really think there's anything overly specific to game development that goes into the crafting of a recruiting strategy for game developers. You could ask for techniques to drive up the popularity of your project among potential game developer recruits, but that is a list-based question (and also only has a very weak basis for a game developer being able to give you a better answer). You could ask how important prior game development experience is to hiring a potential candidate, but that's highly opinion-based because everybody considers that issue differently.

In short, such questions are not off-topic outright but their nature, I think, will generally mean they are off-topic for other reasons.

Comment: I once asked myself "How to hire an artist". I know where to go, I know how much to pay, but I wouldn't know how to write a contract for the artist. I was sure here the question would get a lot of IANAL answers and comments advising to ask a lawyer (which I would of course do if I had money for a lawyer).  Anyway, I found my answer elsewhere and did not try here. Would it be on-topic or off-topic?

Comment: "How to write a contact" would definitely be off-topic I would say.